# Using anonymous types - one variable choose two different queries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to variable take one of two queries but there are two different tables and I have error "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `System.Linq.IQueryable<WGamesTicket>` and `System.Linq.IQueryable<AllGamesTicket>`

```
           var dsakj = (type == "mix") ?
                (from el in objDC.WGamesTickets
                 where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
                     //&& el.typeOfGame == "mix"
                 select el)
                 :
                 (from el in objDC.AllGamesTickets
                  where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
                  //&& el.typeOfGame == "eng"
                  select el);
```

Comment: There are no anoymous types in this question.

Comment: You are right, implicitly typed local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to cast to a new custom class. For example, you're pulling from two different tables, but maybe you want to collect the id and name from each. So change your code to:

```
var dsakj = (type == "mix") ?
            (from el in objDC.WGamesTickets
             where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
                 //&& el.typeOfGame == "mix"
             select new myCustomObject()
             {
                 id = el.id,
                 name = el.name,
             })
             :
             (from el in objDC.AllGamesTickets
              where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
              //&& el.typeOfGame == "eng"
             select new myCustomObject()
             {
                 id = el.id,
                 name = el.name,
             });
```

Answer (score 3):

the result of your queries is of a different type, your first is `IQueryable<WGamesTickets>`, the second `IQueryable<AllGamesTickets>`. For this reason the type for the "var" variable `dsakj` cannot be determined.

You could both project to a common class type:

```
 var dsakj = (type == "mix") ?
                (from el in objDC.WGamesTickets
                 where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
                     //&& el.typeOfGame == "mix"
                 select new GameTicket() { Type = el.typeOfGame} )
                 :
                 (from el in objDC.AllGamesTickets
                  where el.ticket.time == DTtemp
                  //&& el.typeOfGame == "eng"
                  select new GameTicket() { Type = el.typeOfGame} ));
```

This would have the disadvantage though that you have to "manually" copy the properties into the new `GameTicket` class instance.